# How to get a file stored in storage/app/?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I've been trying to store a file to (and get it from) `storage/app/`, following [the doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/filesystem#configuration).

After I run `php artisan storage:link`, I can see that there is a link to the puiblic folder.

[image]

If I put a file with the following code...

```
    Storage::put('/images/blah.png', $file);
```

...the storage will look like this.

[image]

I'm not really sure if the link is working properly, since this `blah.png` can't be retrieved.

So far, I've changed the access level of `storage` by `chmod -R 755 storage/`, and put the complete URL (`http://localhost:8000/storage/images/blah.png`. This is what `asset('storage/images/blah.png')` returns). Still, I'm getting 404 error (Not Found).

In `config/filessystems.php`. the default is set to be `local`. (i.e. `'default' => 'local'`)

Do you see anything I'm doing wrong?

Any advice will be appreciated.

**PS**

This is how the configuration of the public disk looks like...

```
'public' => [
        'driver'     => 'local',
        'root'       => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url'        => env('APP_URL') . '/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
],
 //env('APP_URL').'/storage' returns 'root/storage/app/public'
```

Comment: `storage` is outside of the `public` directory, so will not web accessible.

Comment: @fubar That's the point of `php artisan storage:link`, which makes a symlink in `public/storage` to `storage/app/public`.

Comment: @ceejayoz - I did not know that existed. Irrespective of that point however, OP is storing the file in `storage/app/images`, not `storage/app/public`, so it will remain inaccessible from the web.

Comment: @fubar Good catch. That's almost certainly the issue!

Comment: Thank you @fubar and @ceejayoz. `Storage::put('file name', $file)` doesn't save a file just under `storage/app/public`. I feel like that the link itself isn't working as it's expected.

Answer (score 0):

> The public disk is intended for files that are going to be publicly
>   accessible. By default, the public disk uses the local driver and
>   stores these files in storage/app/public. To make them accessible from
>   the web, you should create a symbolic link from public/storage to
>   storage/app/public.

To create a symbolic link from public/storage to storage/app/public, go to the root folder:

```
ln -s storage/app/public public/storage
```

Then, you can save the file to storage/app/public:

```
Storage::put('/public/images/blah.png', $file);
// the blah.png is located at storage/app/public/images/blah.png
// you can also get the file path by
// $image_path = storage_path() . "/app/public/images/blah.png";
```

Then, you can access the image file as:

```
http://{domain}/storage/images/blah.png
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I still have no luck. Also, isn't `php artisan storage:link` supposed to create the link from `storage/app/public` to `public/storage`?

Comment: did you change the `storage` permission to 0777 recursively?

Answer (score 0):

in the controller

```
Storage::disk('images')->get('firmas.jpg');
```

and in the file config/filesystems.php

```
'default' => env('FILESYSTEM_DRIVER', 'local'),
```

and the disk

```
'disks' => [

    'local' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app'),
    ],

    'images' => [ // used for Backpack/CRUD (in elFinder)
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => storage_path('app/pdfs'),
    ],

    'public' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],

    's3' => [
        'driver' => 's3',
        'key' => env('AWS_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET'),
        'region' => env('AWS_REGION'),
        'bucket' => env('AWS_BUCKET'),
    ],

]
```